# Using WCF to Communicate Interface and Customer Class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple WCF service which I wish to use to send data from client to server, I am unsure of the best way to serialize the data.

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I think that my use of Interfaces and a customer class means that this is not such a simple case.

I have a simple class structure...

```
   public interface IFoo
    {
       IBar MyBar{ get; }
       String SomeInfo{ get; }
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
       String SomeMoreInfo{ get; }
    }


    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
       private IBar _MyBar;
       private String _SomeInfo;

       public String MyBar 
       {
          get { return _MyBar; }
          private set { _MyBar = value; }
       }

       public String SomeInfo 
       {
          get { return _SomeInfo; }
          private set { _SomeInfo= value; }
       }
    }

    public class Bar : IBar
    {
       private String _SomeMoreInfo;

       public String SomeMoreInfo
       {
          get { return _SomeMoreInfo; }
          private set { _SomeMoreInfo= value; }
       }
    }
```

I have a simple WCF service to send this data...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooBarService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool SendFooBar(IFoo request);
}

public class FooBarService : IFooBarService 
{
    public bool SendFooBar(IFoo request)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to send this data from client to server? Should I be using attributes or a DataContractResolver or is my class design flawed for WCF communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/04/13/wcf-using-interfaces-in-method-signatures.aspx

ServiceKnownType and KnownType might be the friends you are looking for: (I have not tested this out completely, so take it with a grain of salt)

```
public interface IFoo
    {
    IBar MyBar { get; }
    String SomeInfo { get; }
    }

public interface IBar
    {
    String SomeMoreInfo { get; }
    }

[DataContract(Name = "Foo")]
[KnownType(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo
    {
    private IBar _MyBar;
    private String _SomeInfo;

    [DataMember(Name = "MyBar")]
    public IBar MyBar
        {
        get { return _MyBar; }
        private set { _MyBar = value; }
        }

    [DataMember(Name = "SomeInfo")]
    public String SomeInfo
        {
        get { return _SomeInfo; }
        private set { _SomeInfo = value; }
        }
    }

[DataContract(Name = "Bar")]
[KnownType(typeof(IBar))]
public class Bar : IBar
    {
    private String _SomeMoreInfo;

    [DataMember(Name = "SomeMoreInfo")]
    public String SomeMoreInfo
        {
        get { return _SomeMoreInfo; }
        private set { _SomeMoreInfo = value; }
        }

    }

[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooBarService
    {
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Foo))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar))]
    bool SendFooBar(IFoo request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally the input parameters of an operation is the data from client to server, and the return data is the data from server to client.

For complex types, you need to define Data Contracts.

When you create a new WCF project through Visual Studio, you get a set of skeleton codes with Service Contracts and Data Contracts. And you will see you should use objects of DataContract classes rather than interfaces to pass data, and there are no explicit codes of doing serialization, since this is done by run time.

Unless you had studied WCF in depth and have some edge and complex cases, you should not need to use DataContractResolver in common business applications.

There are a lot WCF tutorials from the Internet, for example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World